# How to change menu theme in Android

Tags: android, android-theme, android-menu

My android application uses the following style:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme"
parent="android:style/Theme.Holo" ></style>
```

It is assigned for the whole application in the AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    [...]
```

Using this style, menus look like this :

[image]

However, if I use the light theme instead :

```
<style name="AppTheme"
parent="android:style/Theme.Light" ></style>
```

Menus will look like this :

[image]

My question is :

**How can I apply the HOLO theme for the whole application and use only the LIGHT theme for menus ??**

I just want to apply the dialog "style" of the LIGHT theme and apply the HOLO theme for everything else.

Comment: Pretty sure this is possible but haven't figured out how yet. The latest Twitter app has an old style menu (http://cl.ly/image/310e1L3r0515) and Holo-skinned components (http://cl.ly/image/0a3T3H2c1b0D).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
<application
android:theme="@style/theme.holo.light>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "android:itemBackground" to change the background color of the menus

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own white style. Put this into style.xml and give theme in **AndroidManifest** file this theme

```
  <style name="MyGow.Default.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/silver</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: Define Themes in styles.xml

Step-2: Apply the main theme to your whole application in the AndroidManifest.xml

Step-3: Apply theme for the menus through program

```
inside OnCreateOptionMenu(Meny menu){
```

Inflate the menu

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
```

menu theme using contextThemeWrapper

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWtapper(this ,R.style.MenuTheme);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();inflater.inflate(R.memu.main_menu, new menuInflater(ctw));
```