# Android create layout like default OS menu

Tags: android, menu

I want to create a menu layout in my app, which needs to be the same as the default OS menu.
I wanted to start by looking at Android OS code, but I do not know where I can found that are related to menus
Any help is welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to change menu theme in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076863/how-to-change-menu-theme-in-android)

In your Manifest:

you can also try reading this:
http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/android-how-can-you-implement-a-custom-menu-class/

I hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a customized Grid view !